# scrollToRowAtIndexPath when Button inside UITableViewCell is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a tableview with a few custom cells. Inside the first one is a button. When this button is pressed I want to scroll to a certain Section in my tableview. How do I have to link the button action with the tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your cell's button a property and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set the target in the class that loads the table view so you won't need any delegates. Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       static NSString *identifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";
       YourCustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
       if(cell == nil) { 
          cell = [YourCustomCell alloc/init method....
          [cell.buttonProperty addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonTapped:)
                                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       }
       //do other stuff with your cell
}

-(void)cellButtonTapped:(id)sender {
     UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
     YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell*)button.superview.superview; //if the button is added to cell contentView or button.superview is added directly to the cell

    NSIndexPath *path = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path
                         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can scroll to a certain section with using this function :

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

the example of usage is :

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:indexPath.section] 
             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
```

and for link the button action with tableview you can use protocol in you custom cell

Answer (score 1):

Set up a delegation mechanism back from your cell - when creating the cell, assign it an NSIndexPath and pass it back from the cell when the button is tapped.

So in your UITableViewCell subclass you'll have:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
     [self.delegate buttonPressedOnCellAtIndexPath:cell.indexPath]
}
```

Back in the controller that's the delegate, respond to this method with:

```
- (void)buttonPressedOnCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: delegation mechanism? Is there an easier way? I actually dont have to pass anything to the method. I just want to jump to a certain section.

Comment: could you tell me what to put in my .h files so that the delegation works?